# Restarting a loop after a specific number of iterations?

Tags: loops, iteration

I'm new to coding but is being asked to create a simulation of a 10-year experiment 1000 times. I have it at a number lower than 1000 to speed up the testing process. This is a partial copy of my code, I can get the other parameters of the task to work but instead of stopping at and restarting for every 10-years, it seems to accumulate the results of the previous years'.

For example, the code is supposed to compound money earned the year following a 'Success,' while I can get it to compound, my code seems to compound into year 11 and 12 instead of stopping at 10 and essentially restarting at year 1.

I tried .count() to keep track of how many elements I'm iterating through and also tried the while xyz function but I can't seem to get either to work.

```
for sim in range(5):
    for yr in range(10):
        experiment = "Success" if np.random.random() <= 0.1 else "Failure"
        expense = 25000
        margin = 0
        results1.append(experiment)
        expenses1.append(expense)
        margins1.append(margin)
        iter = 0
        if iter < 10:
            for i in range(len(results1)):
                if i + 1 < len(results1) and i - 1 >= 0:
                    if results1[i] == 'Success':
                        expenses1[i + 1] = 0
                        margins1[i + 1] = 10000
                    if results1[i - 1] == 'Success':
                        expenses1[i] = 0
                        if margins1[i] != 10000:
                            margins1[i] = 10000
                    if expenses1[i - 1] == 0:
                        expenses1[i] = 0
                        expenses1[i + 1] = 0
                    if margins1[i] >= 10000:
                        margins1[i + 1] = margins1[i] * 1.2
                    iter += 1
        else:
            continue
            iter = 0
all_data1 = zip(results1, expenses1, margins1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(all_data1, columns=["Results", "R&D", "Margins"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the following simplified code snippet of your implementation.

```
import numpy as np

results1 = []

for sim in range(10):
    for yr in range(10):
        experiment = "Success" if np.random.random() <= 0.1 else "Failure"
        results1.append(experiment)
```

What is the problem here? Well, what I assume you want is that for every year we add a result to a list **for that simulation**. However, what is the difference between what you currently have, and this following code?

```
import numpy as np
    
results1 = []
    
for yr in range(10 * 10):
    experiment = "Success" if np.random.random() <= 0.1 else "Failure"
    results1.append(experiment)
```

Well, unless you left something out of your included code, it looks like not much! You want the simulation to reset after `n` years (in this example 10), but you don't change anything in your code! Here is an example of how this reset could be represented:

```
import numpy as np

results1 = []

for sim in range(10):
    sim_results1 = []
    for yr in range(10):
        experiment = "Success" if np.random.random() <= 0.1 else "Failure"
        sim_results1.append(experiment)
    
    results1.append(sim_results1)
```

Now, your `results1` list will contain `m` lists (where `m` is the number of simulations) with each sublist showing whether the experiment was a success or failure over `n` years. In short: if you just add each experimental result to a big list that is the same across all simulation runs, it's not a surprise that it looks like you are simulating into year 11, 12, etc. What is actually happening is year 11 is really year 1 of simulation number 2, but you do not separate the simulations currently.

Comment: wow thank you; I'll try this out and see how it goes. I upvoted but my reputation is too low for it to show :(

Comment: @CantCodeAtAll Do not worry about that. Please try this and let me know if it fixes your problem. If it does you can select my answer as the "accepted answer" to help others in the future know that it helped you, but please confirm that I have properly identified your issue first.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think that fixed my problem, I think I'm just going to submit my code as is and take whatever repercussion since I spent over a week trying to teach myself python to do this but can't.

Comment: @CantCodeAtAll If you want I can give you my email and we can hop on a chat together and walk through your code if you haven’t already given up.

Comment: We can try that, but I'm being asked to do this task without any prior knowledge on Python until a week ago so the only way "I" can do this is if you do everything. Which, is not going to fly, so while I genuinely appreciate you trying to help out someone as clueless as me, but I think there's someone else on this forum that can be receptive to your expertise and utilize it better than I can.